# create Bitmap from byteArray in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I want to create a bitmap from a bytearray .

I tried the following codes

```
Bitmap bmp;

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

and

```
ByteArrayInputStream bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(data); 
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(bytes); 
bmp = bmd.getBitmap();
```

But ,When i am tring to initialize the Canvas object with the bitmap like

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
```

It leads to an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
```

Then how to get a mutable bitmap from an byteArray.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need a mutable `Bitmap` in order to create the `Canvas`.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap); // now it should work ok
```

Edit: As Noah Seidman said, you can do it without creating a copy.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp); // now it should work ok
```

Comment: Doesn't Bitmap.copy() create a new array entirely? This seems like a waste of memory. I'd love to know how to get a mutable Bitmap directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any other way to obtain a mutable Bitmap(from a `ByteArray`, at least).

Comment: Use BitmapFactory.Options.inMutable = true. You don't need to make a copy, that's a waste.

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options.inMutable is api level 11, so it won't help in all cases

Comment: I'm trying to put RAW data from Camera preview (`onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame,...`) but this method I guess eats only PNG/JPG bytes