# Creating a mutable Bitmap from ByteArray... import not working?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp;
BitmapFactory.Options.inMutable = true;
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

But I'm getting an error under `BitmapFactory.Options.inMutable = true;`

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field BitmapFactory.Options.inMutable

I'm sure the solution is probably something simple, but I'm unsure of why it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the BitmapFactory.Options class. Something like:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.lentgh, options);
```

Comment: Will try this. I just was using the code snippet from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359173/create-bitmap-from-bytearray-in-android

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

inMutable is not static field. Try this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inMutable = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length(), opts);
```

or even better this:

```
Bitmap bmp;
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Comment: Hmmm... I took my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359173/create-bitmap-from-bytearray-in-android but it seems like copy should be used because of memory.