# Send picture from Android app to server http post

Tags: java, android, bitmap, http-post

I'm trying to figure out the best way to send a bitmap to a webserver to store into a database. Right now, I am sending a string placeName to the server like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("mywebserver");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("placeName",placeName));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

This is successful. Now, basically what I want to do is something like this

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("placePhoto",photo));
//obviously pseudocode
```

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In first side decode bitmap into byte array
 2) In other side - create bitmap from byte array.

[BitmapFactory documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int))

> [Bitmap TO byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array)
>   [Bitmap FROM byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359173/create-bitmap-from-bytearray-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert the Bitmap to a byte array. And then Base64 encode the byte array to a String photoBase64; Then you can put it as name-value pair ("placePhoto", photoBase64). On the receiving side reverse.

How to do the conversions is easy to find on this site.